# add <clear /> and <remove name=something /> tag to collections in applicationHost.config or web.config using Powershell webadministration module

Tags: shell, powershell, iis-7, scripting

as per title, can someone help?

just an example:

```
<system.ftpServer>
    <security>
        <ipSecurity>
            <add ipAddress="1.2.3.4" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" />
        </ipSecurity>
    </security>
</system.ftpServer>
```

I would like to add a  tag as the first element to stop the elements delegated from its parent. 
and a  after  as well.

So it will look like this:

```
<system.ftpServer>
    <security>
        <ipSecurity>
            <clear />
            <remove ipAddress="1.1.1.1" />
            <add ipAddress="1.2.3.4" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" />
        </ipSecurity>
    </security>
</system.ftpServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without resorting to xml manipulation, the following answer may help you get started with this problem:

[Add a 'clear' element to WebDAV authoringRules using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619944/add-a-clear-element-to-webdav-authoringrules-using-powershell/16734064#16734064)

Answer (score 0):

This approach might not be recommended but if you want to do it using xml then here is how you can do it.

```
$filepath = "C:\scripts\so\webdavconfig.xml"
$xml = [xml](get-Content -Path $filepath)
$elem = $xml.CreateElement("clear");
$elem2 = $xml.CreateElement("remove");
$attr = $xml.CreateAttribute("ipAddress");
$attr.Value="1.1.1.1";
$elem2.Attributes.Append($attr);
$xmlnode = $xml."system.ftpserver".security.ipSecurity
$xmlnode.AppendChild($elem);
$xmlnode.AppendChild($elem2);
$xml.Save($filepath);
$xml."system.ftpserver".security.ipSecurity
```